# UICollectionViewFlowLayout weird behaviour

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout wity my UICollectionView for showing a horizontal line of images.

The idea is something like this (sample with 3 cells):

```
-------------------
|cell1|cell2|cell3|
-------------------
```

but I am getting something like

```
-------------------
|cell1|cell2|     
------|cell3|------
```

After scrolling, the cell3 moves to the right position.

In iPad (landscape) the size of my cells is (480,640), and my UIEdgeInsets is (150,150,150,150).

I don't know what is going on, any idea?